# About method chaining on Lists

Tags: c#, list

Why do methods such as `List<T>.Reverse()` modify the `List` instead of returning a new one? I'd really like to chain methods and write neat one-liners.

Is there an advantage in terms of resource usage and efficiency for doing this? To me something like

```
myList = myList.Reverse().RemoveAll(...);
```

etc. makes more sense (and looks much better) than having each modification statement on it's own line.

I understand that `myList.RemoveAll(...)` is shorter than `myList = myList.RemoveAll(...)`, but it's only more convenient when it's a single statement.

Comment: `System.Linq` is your friend.

Comment: You can use `Enumerable.Reverse(myList)` or `myList.AsEnumerable().Reverse()`

Comment: I see. I usually don't use Linq unless necessary, but I guess I'll be using it pretty often from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

"Why API shaped in particular way" is really opinion based question. Fluent API is not universally accepted as "the best thing" and other approaches are perfectly valid too.

Now the particular case of "why `List.Reverse()` does not return copy/this" have solid reason so answering that part:

Fact that [`Reverse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c6526tb(v=vs.110).aspx) method does not return value API indicates that method modifies existing list. It prevents possibility of multiple interpretations of behavior if method would return `List` - by looking at `List Reverse()` signature one can't say whether method returns same object or clone in reversed order.